# Как достать текст из аннотации @FindBy

Tags: selenium

Есть тесты на selenide.(Решение и для selenium подойдет).

Допустим есть некий элемент.

```
@FindBy(css = "login_field")
@Name("Логин")
private SelenideElement loginField;
```

Можно как-то вытащить текст аннотации `@FindBy` ? В методах не нашел, думал как-то при создании где-то сохраняется в виде переменной указанный `selector`, но не нашел.
Можно попробовать через рефлексию, но есть вариант не такой жесткий?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@class=\"value\"]")
        private WebElement value;

    public String getText(String value){
        return value.getText();
    }

String text = getText(value);
```